# Garbage collection in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Does bash run a garbage collector? Can it be controlled via some command line options? I can't find anything on the net about this.

I have a bash script that runs and over a few days its memory usage increases. I want to know where the memory is going.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not, but I'm curious why you ask.

Comment: What does bash need to collect? It runs other processes, and reaps them as they finish. The variables you set are your responsibility.

Comment: @vanza: So should one somehow cleanup the variables used when they are not needed?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I have a bash script that runs and over a few days its memory usage increases. I want to know where the memory is going.

Comment: Do you have any arrays in your script?  Are they associative arrays?  If you have either type of array, they could be a source of growth.  Have you considered using local variables and functions, so that the variables are destroyed?  Which version of `bash` are you using?  Is it the latest?  If not, have you tried with the latest?  Have you tried running your script under `valgrind` (well, run `bash` under `valgrind` and have it execute your script)?  Have you considered breaking the big script into smaller ones that are executed as needed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bash does not run a garbage collector as such. Since it has no concept of references, there is no need to find data without references. It does free memory no longer in use, though.

Here's a simple demonstration of memory usage before and after declaring and overwriting a large variable. Memory usage goes up then down again:

```
ps -o rss -p $$
var=$(printf "%s\n" {1..100000})
ps -o rss -p $$
var="smallstring"
ps -o rss -p $$
```